# React Native, Android, undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push')

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to navigate from login screen to home screen on submit `button`click...
Following is my fucnction for navigation

```
  onsubmitButtonPress(event)
{
  if(User != null && password != null){
    if(User != '' && password != ''){
    if (User == password){
      ToastAndroid.show('Login Successful', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      this.props.navigator.push({
              title: 'Home',
              component: HomeScreen,
            });
    }else{
      ToastAndroid.show('Login Failed', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    }
  }else{
    ToastAndroid.show('Fill details', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
  }
  }else{
    ToastAndroid.show('Fill details', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
  }
}
```

But I'm getting this error.Can anybody help me out..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely how you're calling `onsubmitButtonPress`.  Change where you set it on your component from this:

`someProp={this.onsubmitButtonPress}`

to this:

`someProp={(e) => this.onsubmitButtonPress(e)}`

The issue being that `this` is not defined.

If it's NOT that, then it's likely that you're never defining `this.props.navigator`.  Put a breakpoint (or a console.log) in your function there to log the value of `this.props` and check if it exists, and if it does, if `this.props.navigator` is defined on it.